# Perturbing a function to make the ratios distinct

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given two positive-valued functions $f, g: [0,1]\to(0,1)$, say that the pair $(f,g)$ is *good* if, for every real number $r$, the set

$$ Z_r :=  \{x ~\big|~ {g(x) / f(x)} = r \} $$

has a measure of zero in $\mathbb{R}$.

For example, if $f(x)=1/2$ and $g(x)=(x+1)/2$ then the pair $(f,g)$ is good, since for every real $r$, the set $Z_r$ is either empty or a singleton (it contains only the element $r-1$).

As a negative example, if $f(x)=1/2$ and $g(x)=3/4$, then the pair $(f,g)$ is not good, since $Z_{3/2}$ has a measure of 1.

QUESTION: Given a pair $(f,g)$ and a constant $\epsilon>0$, does there always exist a function $h: [0,1]\to [0,\epsilon]$ such that the pair $(f, g+h)$ is good?

I.e., is it always possible to make a pair "good" by a slight perturbation?

NOTE: In my use-case, all functions are integrable. I am not sure this is relevant.

Comment: Are there any assumptions made on $f$ or $g$ or $h$?

Comment: @Mick In my use-case, all the functions are integrable. I am not sure if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if both $f$ and $g$ are continuous, unless $f/g$ is strictly monotone, this is not possible (essentially intermediate value theorem).

The auxiliary issue of merely $L^1$ functions raises the probably-irrelevant issue of pointwise-versus-almost-everywhere-pointwise. Do you really care about that?

Maybe this is only a half-answer, in the sense that there are potential issues with the question as it stands which make definitive answers difficult. Clarify?

Comment: I modified the question accordingly. Is it clearer now?